Word Documents with Broken Links Taking Too Long to Save
We frequently receive Word documents (.doc or .docx format) in emails via Outlook, and some of these documents contain broken links. The issue arises when we make changes to these documents and try to save them—it takes over 30 seconds, probably because Word is trying (and failing) to access the content from these broken links online.
Through trial and error, I discovered that manually removing the broken links significantly reduces the save time. However, this isn’t practical given the volume of emails we handle daily. Interestingly, this problem seems to affect only .doc files, not .docx.
I also tried using the "Break Links" feature in Word, but it causes Word to freeze temporarily (showing "Not Responding"). When the links finally load, breaking them not only removes the links but also deletes images and other graphics in the document, which I don’t want.
I’ve tried running Word in offline mode, and even upgraded from Word 2007 to Word 2019, but the issue remains the same.
Is there any way to adjust timeout settings in Word/Office to stop it from trying to load broken links? Or any other suggestions to fix this problem without manually removing the links every time?

You can remove all hyperlinks at once, if that is acceptable -- right-click one link and select remove all. The timeout is likely only from the global TCP/IP setting, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-modify-the-tcp-ip-maximum-retransmission-time-out-7ae0982a-4963-fa7e-ee79-ff6d0da73db8, which you wouldn't want to change, as it would affect web use.

Are your documents somehow downloading text from the hyperlinks?  It seems unusual that Word would check whether a link was valid or not when saving.  Are you opening docs directly from email and then saving?  Would it help to drag the doc to your files and then open for editing?
